# UIWebview constraint not adjusting

Tags: swift, xcode, uiwebview, constraints, uislider

So, I have a webview and its content font can increase/decrease by the slider. When I slide up the font size is increasing as well as the webview constraint to fit the content. But when I slide down, the constraint still at the last state when I slide up, it won't change, but the font decrease. So I have a lot of empty space because the height constraint doesn't change.

```
@objc func changeFontSize(_ sender: UISlider!) {
        let webViewSize = 16 * sender.value
        let jsString = "document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.fontSize='\(webViewSize)px'"
        webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: jsString)
        webViewDidFinishLoad(webView) 
}
```

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        let webViewTextSize = webView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0))
        var webViewFrame = webView.frame
        webViewFrame.size.height = webViewTextSize.height
        webView.frame = webViewFrame
        webHeightConstraints.constant = webViewTextSize.height
        webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        webView.scrollView.bounces = false
    }
```

That is my code, and I've tried to changed `webHeightConstraints.constant` to `webview.scrollView.contentSize.height` but got the same result. All the other values are changed according to the slider, only the height constraint. It changes only when the slides up, and then remain at that value.

Answer (score 0):

I also face same kind of issue. try to clear webview when slide up and down, that will work here is code for clear webview.

```
final class WebCacheCleaner {

    class func clear() {
        URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
        HTTPCookieStorage.shared.removeCookies(since: Date.distantPast)

        WKWebsiteDataStore.default().fetchDataRecords(ofTypes: WKWebsiteDataStore.allWebsiteDataTypes()) { records in
            records.forEach { record in
                WKWebsiteDataStore.default().removeData(ofTypes: record.dataTypes, for: [record], completionHandler: {})
                print("[WebCacheCleaner] Record \(record) deleted")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

call like this `WebCacheCleaner.clear()`

Comment: I've added `WebCacheCleaner.clear()` before `webViewDidFinishLoad(webView)` it called but doesn't change a thing

Comment: can you please add that before silde down?

Comment: and check when you side down the value of "webview.scrollView.contentSize.height" is change if not then I m sure after using the above code problem will solve.